# Automatic variables for form inputs in events, is this standard?

Tags: javascript, forms, cross-browser

A friend of mine just showed me the following snippet:

```js
function copy(src, dst) {
  dst.value = src.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="myInput1" onkeyup="copy(myInput1, myInput2)" />
  <input name="myInput2" />
</form>
```

I am aware that the best practice here is to search for the element by ID or by some other way instead of referencing the input names.

I noticed that the form is in scope at the moment the event fires, which explains why the input is reachable:

[image]

**Is this standard behavior? If not, which browsers support it?**

Comment: It isn't standard as far as I can recall, it's a remnant from the Dark Days™ of IE. Don't count on it being there forever.